# Splitting Sonar test run and analysis phases

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, sonarqube

We're using Jenkins and attempting to make our project's CI build as modular as possible, i.e. independent jobs for checkout/build/test/analysis/deploy which can then be chained together as and when needed.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to get Sonar to only run tests or only run analysis. Regarding the former, I'm completely lost; for the latter, I understand I can set `sonar.dynamicAnalysis = reuseReport`. But our tests are in MSTest format and we use Gallio to run them, and since Sonar only seems to support [surefire/cobertura/clover report files](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Advanced+parameters#Advancedparameters-Dynamicanalysis) - not Gallio/MSTest - I'm not sure how to get Sonar to read the test output.

So how do I get Sonar to split its test and analysis phases?

Comment: which runner are you using? Maven, ant or command line?

Comment: The Sonar plugin for Jenkins: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Hudson+and+Jenkins+Plugin

Answer (score 2):

IMO, you could let Sonar handle tests and analysis at the same time - this will make your configurations far simpler (=> using "reuseReport" can lead to lors of troubles if assemblies have been moved between the build/test and the Sonar analysis).

So basically, what I'm saying is that in your "analysis" job, Sonar would do test + static analysis. That's what we do at SonarSource, we have:

- a continuous integration process that does "checkout/build/test/deploy" on every commit
- a continuous inspection process that does ""checkout/build/sonar" every night